# How to tell python to distinguish datetime format > (01/01/2020) MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For my case, i need to merge two csv file,
File A = (2/4/2021  12:44:11 AM) = (d/m/yyyy h:m:s) ,
File B = (04/02/2021 12:40:51AM) = text(does not have type)

when i merge two file, python will auto read file B datetime as (d/m/yyyy h:m:s) but actually is (m/d/yyyy h:m:s),

my problem is how to tell python read File B datetime in format (d/m/yyyy h:m:s)?

```
    ## Coding File A
       global df_DATACUR
                df_DATACUR = pd.read_excel(dataCurvefile, skiprows=5)
                df_DATACUR
                df_DATACUR.rename(columns={'Time': 'DateTime'}, inplace=True)
                df_DATACUR['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_DATACUR['DateTime'])
                df_DATACUR = df_DATACUR.drop(['No'], axis=1)
                df_DATACUR = df_DATACUR.set_index('DateTime').resample('1S').pad()
                df_DATACUR
    
                lb.insert("end",dataCurvefile)
                newWindow.destroy()
```

```
    ## Coding File B
       global df_LOG
                df_LOG = pd.read_csv(dataloggerfile, encoding='unicode_escape', skiprows=5)
                df_LOG.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep=False, inplace=True)
                df_LOG.rename(columns={'Date/Time': 'DateTime'}, inplace=True)
                df_LOG['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_LOG['DateTime'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
                df_LOG.sort_values('DateTime', inplace=True)
                df_LOG = df_LOG[~df_LOG.DateTime.duplicated(keep='first')]
                df_LOG = df_LOG.set_index('DateTime').resample('1S').pad()
    
                lb.insert("end", dataloggerfile)
```

```
>> Actually these coding can function in certain condition if the day and month does not overlapping. 
Condition one: (18/02/2021), day>12, python auto detect it as 'DD/MM/YY'
input date : File A > (18/2/2021  12:10:13 PM)
             File B > (02/18/2021 12:05:03PM)
>Output:
```

```
                        ID Enter D.B.Temp.@TR8(℃)  ...  DIO 7
    DateTime                                        ...       
    2021-02-18 12:10:13                      10.20  ...      1
    2021-02-18 12:10:14                      10.20  ...      1
    2021-02-18 12:10:15                      10.20  ...      1
    2021-02-18 12:10:16                      10.20  ...      1
    2021-02-18 12:10:17                      10.20  ...      1
    ...                                        ...  ...    ...
    2021-02-18 13:19:54                       9.96  ...      1
    2021-02-18 13:19:55                       9.96  ...      1
    2021-02-18 13:19:56                       9.96  ...      1
    2021-02-18 13:19:57                       9.96  ...      1
    2021-02-18 13:19:58                       9.96  ...      1
    
    [4186 rows x 83 columns]
```

```
>>but if the day and month < than 12, python will directly read it as ('DD/MM/YY') and the output will show empty even though the actual date is ('MM/DD/YY')
Condition two:(02/04/2021), day<12, python auto detect it as 'MM/DD/YY', the time does not match and the data will not fill in.
input date: [File A > (2/4/2021  12:44:11 AM)]
            [File B > (04/02/2021 12:40:51AM)]
>Output:
```

```
                         ID Enter D.B.Temp.@TR8(℃)  ...  DIO 7
    DateTime                                        ...       
    2021-04-02 00:44:11                      29.82  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 00:44:12                      29.82  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 00:44:13                      29.82  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 00:44:14                      29.82  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 00:44:15                      29.82  ...    NaN
    ...                                        ...  ...    ...
    2021-04-02 02:12:07                      30.02  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 02:12:08                      30.02  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 02:12:09                      30.02  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 02:12:10                      30.02  ...    NaN
    2021-04-02 02:12:11                      30.02  ...    NaN
    
    [5281 rows x 118 columns]
```

Comment: Read separately, convert string to datetime, and *then* merge. Please provide some code you use if you need more detailed help.

Comment: Since you're using pandas, pd.to_datetime has a keyword `dayfirst`; set e.g. `dayfirst = True` if the day comes first in the input string

Comment: if i use `dayfirst`, python will auto detect 1st number in datetime as day right? but for my file B, date is come with month first, the result will remain unchange right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Since you seem to have specific code for importing each file, you can just set the keyword there. Otherwise, you would have to find a criterion to distinguish the input files. So that if it's "File A", `dayfirst` is set True, and if it's "File B", `dayfirst` is set False.

Comment: i try that but seem like not function, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I think for File A you want `pd.to_datetime(df_DATACUR['DateTime'], dayfirst=True)`, for File B `pd.to_datetime(df_LOG['DateTime'], dayfirst=False)`

Comment: I found the solution, the problem is due to the column. Thanks for the suggestion.